# Get sum of latest 5 per id

Tags: sql, mariadb

So I have a query, and this query has to tell me if the result SUM of the last 5 runs per ID, has a different verdict than 'SUCCESS'. I wrote this query

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN testresults.StatusId != 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS StatusId
FROM
    testreporting.testresults
WHERE
    TestSuiteCollectionId = 461
        AND TestCaseId IN ('3846', '3846', '3840', '3841', '3842', '3845', '5701', '4015', '4008', '3844', '4012', '5702', '3843', '4014', '3847', '4635', '4295', '4446', '4637', '4296', '4297', '443'
'3846')
GROUP BY TestCaseId, TestSuiteId, TestSuiteCollectionId
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I wanted to do a LIMIT 5, but that doesn't make sense, because I limit my results table to 5 then.

How can I make this query get the last 5 results for each `TestCaseId`, and then do the `SUM != 1`?

It would work if I took one testcase ID at the time like this

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN testresults.StatusId != 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS StatusId
FROM
    testreporting.testresults
WHERE
    TestSuiteCollectionId = 461
        AND TestCaseId = ('4296')
GROUP BY TestCaseId, TestSuiteId, TestSuiteCollectionId
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

But that wouldn't be efficient, because I have to run this query many times.

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather inelegant method that works in very old versions of MariaDB that do not support window functions uses `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT TestCaseId, TestSuiteId, TestSuiteCollectionId,
       (GROUP_CONCAT(tr.StatusId ORDER BY id DESC) LIKE '1,1,1,1,1%') as StatusId
FROM testreporting.testresults tr
WHERE TestSuiteCollectionId = 461 AND
      TestCaseId IN ('3846', '3846', '3840', '3841', '3842', '3845', '5701', '4015', '4008', '3844', '4012', '5702', '3843', '4014', '3847', '4635', '4295', '4446', '4637', '4296', '4297', '443'
'3846')
GROUP BY TestCaseId, TestSuiteId, TestSuiteCollectionId
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: What does this part do? `GROUP_CONCAT(tr.StatusId ORDER BY id DESC) LIKE '1,1,1,1,1%'`

Comment: I can see that if one of the 5 is another value than 1, then statusId returns 0, this is better than what I had, but I would like to get the amount of statusId != 1, because depending on the value I write how bad the test is.  `5/5 = all status is 1 = 0` and `3/5 = 2 status is not 1 = 2`

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup . . . It checks the first five statuses.  This answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a different question, you should ask that as a new question.

Comment: It's very slow when it's running for 10.000 results.

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup . . . MariaDB introduced window functions more than five years ago.  I would suggest that you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this work for you. Used `ROW_NUMBER` ordered by `ID DESC` to generate row numbers and then filered out the ones that are `<= 5` so that should be last five runs.

```
SELECT 
    TestCaseId, SUM(CASE WHEN StatusId != 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StatusId
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TestCaseId ORDER BY ID DESC) AS row_number
    FROM testresults
    WHERE TestSuiteCollectionId = 461
      AND TestCaseId = ('4296')
)
WHERE row_number <= 5
GROUP BY TestCaseId
```

Comment: cant run ` SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TestCaseId ORDER BY ID DESC) AS row_number
    FROM testresults`